# Checkbox is not toggling when it is clicked in react component

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, components

When I click the checkbox, it is supposed to turn green to signify that it has been selected. However the checkbox does nothing. Here is the code for the react component handling the checkbox:

```
import classNames from "classnames"
import { useRef } from "react"
import { InputCheckboxComponent } from "./types"

export const InputCheckbox: InputCheckboxComponent = ({ id, checked = false, disabled, onChange }) => {
  const { current: inputId } = useRef(`RampInputCheckbox-${id}`)

  return (
    <div className="RampInputCheckbox--container" data-testid={inputId}>
      <label
        className={classNames("RampInputCheckbox--label", {
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-checked": checked,
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-disabled": disabled,
        })}
      />
      <input
        id={inputId}
        type="checkbox"
        className="RampInputCheckbox--input"
        checked={checked}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={() => onChange(!checked)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm thinking the issue has to do with the  tag.

[click here to see a photo of the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXwOO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your checkbox component should have its internal state, based on provided 'checked' prop:

```js
import classNames from "classnames"
import { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { InputCheckboxComponent } from "./types"

export const InputCheckbox: InputCheckboxComponent = ({ id, checked = false, disabled, onChange }) => {
  const { current: inputId } = useRef(`RampInputCheckbox-${id}`)
  const [_checked, setChecked] = useState(checked);

  return (
    <div className="RampInputCheckbox--container" data-testid={inputId}>
      <label
        className={classNames("RampInputCheckbox--label", {
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-checked": _checked,
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-disabled": disabled,
        })}
      />
      <input
        id={inputId}
        type="checkbox"
        className="RampInputCheckbox--input"
        checked={_checked}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={() => {
          setChecked(!_checked)
          onChange(!_checked)
        }
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```